# How to prevent antivirus from detecting my own program messing with registry keys

Tags: c#, antivirus

So I like to game, a lot, and sometimes it gets in the way of being productive, so i wanted to make a program that changes the registry Keys, in a way that everytime I tried to play a game it would show a random math problem,I made the program. The problem is, the program changes registry keys, so my antivírus stops the program from running.I want to know if there is a way to prevent that, besides adding a exception in the antivirus(Avast btw).

Below are the line that changes the registry keys.

(and sorry for the bad english)

```cs
    using (RegistryKey gamekey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Image File Execution Options\\RainbowSix.exe",true))
                {
                    if (gamekey==null)
                    {
                        Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\RainbowSix.exe", true);
                    }
                    gamekey.SetValue("Debugger", @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyPrograms\MathProblem", RegistryValueKind.String);                 
                }
```

Comment: Your anti-virus might pay nicer with a signed executable.

Comment: Rephrase your question as "Can I write a program that can bypass virus protection?" Surely you can see the answer is "I hope not" otherwise why wouldn't the virus writers exploit the same loophole ?

Comment: @John3136 well, that's a negative attitude.  There's lots of legitimate reasons for a program to write to the registry and not all of them should get caught by AV.  The OP is trying to solve a legitimate problem with code.  A better question might be "why does my AV think this code is risky?" but that might be too opinion-based.

Comment: @Joe We'll have to agree to disagree. I think it is a safe attitude. As others have suggested there are ways around this - rules in your AV, signing the app, but if there was a general way to make any old exe bypass AV checks then that would be bad

Comment: There ought to be a way to whitelist your program with your antivirus. Have you looked into that?